# Fast find near users using PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 5 tables:

```
- users - information about user with current location_id (fk to geo_location_data)
- geo_location_data - information about location, with PostGIS geography(POINT, 4326) column
- user_friends - relationships between users.
```

I want to find near friends for current user, but it takes a lot of time of executing select query to know if user is a friend and after that execute select using `ST_DWithin`. May be something wrong in domain model or in queries?

Comment: Could you please post the query you are using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to index the geometry column.  Something like this:

```
  CREATE INDEX geo_location_data_the_geom_idx ON geo_location_data USING GIST (the_geom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a buffer on your points and the the intersects operator.

```
SELECT ... FROM A, B WHERE Intersects(B.the_geom, ST_Buffer(A,1000))
```

It should be faster.